# MULE ESB : How to fix the error : org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner: doSelect exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, mule-esb

I am using `MULE ESB version 3.8.1` and exposing a synchronous `SOAP` Web service using `HTTP` and `CXF` component. The service is working fine for say 100 requests in a minute.

But when I am using SoapUI to perform LOAD testing and sending requests as follows:
12 threads, active for 300 seconds, and sending burst requests the load on ESB server is pretty high and I get the error :

> org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner: doSelect exception
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

My question is :

How can I configure mule ESB flows or tune the performance in mule ESB so that I can increase the performance to process 10 requests per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a problem with your operating system configuration. See the recommendations at  https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/OutOfMemoryError-unable-to-create-new-native-thread-How-to-prevent-it on how to troubleshoot.

Also 3.8.1 might have many bugs already fixed in later version a. As of today 3.9.2 is much more robust.